# Eclipse Java formatters

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

Eclipse (as of now) comes with 3 formatters: "Java Conventions", "Eclipse" and "Eclipse 2.1".
In order to get any other formatter (ex. Google Style), one has to know what to look for.

- Is there an Eclipse suite which contains a collection of formatters?
- If not, is there a reference that has a list of links to various
  formatters?

P.S. Please note that I am only asking about *existence* of a feature/resource and not seeking any recommendations or opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't different formatters, they're different profiles for the built-in Java formatter. If you're looking for the Google Style, you can just get the profile with it at https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml and import that.